# Probability of picking two letters from the word MATHEMATICAL

Tags: probability

If you select 3 letters (with replacement) from the word MATHEMATICAL, what is the probability of getting two 'M's.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I get 5/72 as well. But the correct answer is 11/144. Could some one please explain this answer to me. Thx.

Comment: I do not agree with the answer of 11 / 144.

Comment: I tend to agree with you. But the answer in the text book is 11/144

Comment: The textbook's answer is wrong.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

How many letters are there in the word MATHEMATICAL? $12$

How many letters are $M$ here? $2$

We want the probability of getting two 'M's takes considering all three cases. When we get a non-M on the first, second or third pick.

$\frac{10}{12}*\frac{2}{12}*\frac{2}{12}+\frac{2}{12}*\frac{10}{12}*\frac{2}{12}+\frac{2}{12}*\frac{2}{12}*\frac{10}{12}=30*\frac{2^2}{12^3}=\frac{5}{72}$

Answer (score 3):

The number of M's obtained is binomially distributed with $p={1\over6}$. The probability to obtain exactly two M's in three draws is therefore given by
$${3\choose 2}\ \left({1\over6}\right)^2\ \left({5\over6}\right)^1={5\over72}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

I am getting,

$$3\left ( \frac{2}{12}\right )\left ( \frac{2}{12}\right )\left ( \frac{10}{12}\right )=\frac{5}{72}$$

Comment: Why do we have three answers? What is wrong with my method and/or $8\pi \mathrm{r}$'s?

Comment: I think because I am treating (m,m,X) as different than (X,m,m) and (m,X,m).

Comment: Oh good point, thank you for that!

Comment: I am your upvote here, and I have no idea why I got one more upvote than you, considering my answer was obtained from your help!

Comment: It us not a big deal, glad you got them. Looks like they are closing the question anyway.